# Vtype for Companies Name

Tags: regex

I have a vtype trying to check for names like:

99Balls SRL

My-Company S.A.

Company S.A.

I need the vtype to allow only one . or - or space at a time. So, My--Company would return false.

This is what I did but it's not working:

```
var alfanumericoTest = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9]*-?\.? ');
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    //  vtype validation function
    alfanumerico: function(val, field) {
        return alfanumericoTest.test(val);
    },
    // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
    alfanumericoText: 'Ingrese palabras.',
    // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
    alfanumericoMask: new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9]|-|\.| ')
});
```

Also, what this means?:

```
alfanumerico: function(val, field) {
      return alfanumericoTest.test(val);
},
```

Is that a function? It is declared in a way I never seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and added the 'g' modifier for Global match.

```
// Alfanumerico
  var alfanumericoTest = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z0-9]+\.?\-? ?','g');
  Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    //  vtype validation function
    alfanumerico: function(val, field) {
      return alfanumericoTest.test(val);
    },
    // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
    alfanumericoText: 'Ingrese palabras.',
    // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
    alfanumericoMask: new RegExp('[A-Za-z0-9\-\.\ ]')
  });
```